# What's needed for JSON besides setting up API in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

As far as I understand, for AJAX generally js/jquery are used, so if I plan some AJAX actions for action, I should add `format.js {...}`.

I googled this problem and as far as i understand, main JSON use is for creating application's API.

Any other reasons to include `format.json` and json rendering in the application?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a common misunderstanding.

Sending `http request` through `Ajax` has nothing to do with rendering `HTTP response` in a specific format. Writing in the `controller action` `fromat.js{.....}` or `format.html{...}` has nothing to do with `AJAX`. it is just you are telling your `controller action` to respond based on the request `format`. regardless to how the request send.

When you send `AJAX` request you can determine the expected `data type` or `content-type` by using the following `$.ajax` attribute `dataType: "json"`.

For creating `APIs` as far as I know most of `apis` if not all of them are using either `xml` or `json`. the latter has become very popular. Most of the newly built `apis` are built to send data in a `json` format.

So when you built you `API` you need to design you `action response` to be in a `json format`. There are many ways to do such a thing.

My favourite way is to build a `json view` this can be done using `jbuilder` which is included by default as a `gem` when you create a `new rails app` OR use the my favourite `json builder gem` which is `rabl`.